# Compare symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to compare two symbolic variables (numbers). The whole problem boils down to the following code.

```
R = vpa(0.555555555555555555555555555);
isAlways(R>R*(1-sym(10^(-10))))
isAlways(R>R*(1-sym(10^(-50))))
```

Both comparisons should return `1`, but the second returns `0`.

---

My solution:

```
digits(51);
R = vpa(0.555555555555555555555555555);
isAlways(R>R*(1-sym(10^(-10))))
isAlways(R>R*(1-sym(10^(-50))))
```

Comment: [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)'s default precision is 32 digits, if you want to compare out to 50 then you need to specify an appropriate precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why you encounter this problem

[`vpa`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) **evaluates** symbolic inputs with variable-precision floating-point arithmetic (32 significant digits by default)... So what's happening in your case is

```
>> R = vpa(0.555555555555555555555555555)

R =

0.55555555555555555555555555555556

>> R*(1-sym(10^(-50)))

ans =

0.55555555555555555555555555555556
```

32 digits are definitely not enough to store the actual value of `1-10^(-50)`.

### How to fix it

Without stressing with `vpa()` you can declare both `R` and `R * (1 - 10^(-50))` as symbolics (in fact `0.5555555... = 5/9`), and compare them:

```
>> R = str2sym('5/9');
>> X = str2sym('5/9 * (1 - 10^(-50))');
>> isAlways(R > X)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Comment: I think it's worth to say thank you to @LuisMendo, before edit your answer based on his comment.

Comment: No problem! Deleting comment to avoid confusion